# Set of the vertex sets to make connected graph into disjoint sets of vertices?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, terminology, connectedness

Suppose a non-directed graph G with vertices V and paths P. What is the name for the vertex sets to make break the graph by removal of some vertices?

Comment: Are you talking about [cut sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28graph_theory%29)?

Comment: Wait, do you want to have zero edges after removing the vertices? Or do you just want it to be disconnected? If it is the first option what you want is a dominating set

Comment: @JMoravitz if this cut set is defined only by the removal of edges, not vertices, no -- I am trying to find a term to describe the removal of vertices in which case relevant associated edges will dissappear: this is partially also edge removal but the focus is on removal of vertices instead of edges. Is this still called `"cut set"` in graph theory?

Comment: In my experience, they can be used for either "cut vertex sets" or "cut edge sets".  Another name that it sometimes goes by is [vertex separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_separator).  In general, if a graph is $k$-connected there does not exist $k-1$ vertices that you can delete which disconnects the graph.

Comment: In infinite graph theory Dunwoody and Krön (to the best of my knowledge Dunwoody was first) called such things edge and vertex cuts. However for them (any others) an edge/vertex cut is a set of vertices with finite edge/vertex boundary (that is the set of edges/vertices which are connected with exactly one vertex of the edge/vertex cut). They have developed a beautiful theory (see the paper "Vertex cuts" by Dunwoody, Krön and also the book "Groups acting on Graphs" by Dicks, Dunwoody) which also applies to finite graphs.

Answer (score 2):

I list below the relevant things in Mathematics. In comparison, the computing perspectives and visualisation more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116470/mincuts-from-graphs-to-find-permutations-that-break-the-system-into-disjoint-set).

## Theorems and Lemmas

> - [Planar separator theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_separator_theorem)
> - [Tutte theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_theorem) related to edge cuts
> - [Minimal vertex separator lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_separator#Minimal_separators)
>
> [image]
>
> - [Menger's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem) has vertex-connectivity version and edge-connectivity version

**Examples**

> **Dominating set** suggested in the comment by [dREaM](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/33907/dream), from dominating sets to set coverings in L-reductions [here, Wikipedia about dominating set example below.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set)
>
> [image]
>
> **Cut set** and [**vertex separator**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_separator) suggested in the comment by JMoravitz [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1600059/set-of-the-vertex-sets-to-make-connected-graph-into-disjoint-sets-of-vertices#comment3259265_1600059) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1600059/set-of-the-vertex-sets-to-make-connected-graph-into-disjoint-sets-of-vertices#comment3259283_1600059), respectively. The examples are from the vertex separator Wikipedia article.
>
> [image]
>
> **Vertex cuts and edge cuts** suggested in the comment by [M.U.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1600059/set-of-the-vertex-sets-to-make-connected-graph-into-disjoint-sets-of-vertices#comment3259285_1600059) related to infinite graph theory by Dunwoody and Krön, more in the paper *["Vertex Cuts"](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.0064.pdf)* by Dunwoody, Krön, also possible to apply to finite graphs according to M.U.
>
> **Graph separators, graph bifurcators, graph boundaries** -- loosely speaking result into two separate subgraphs after removal of some vertices or some edges. (On page 12 of Graph Separators, with Applications by Arnold L. Rosenberg, et all).

**References**

> - [Vertex cuts](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.0064.pdf) publication by Dunwoody, Krön as suggested by M.U.
> - Book *"Groups acting on Graphs"* by Dicks, Dunwoody suggested by M.U.
> - [A Separator Theorem for Planar Graphs](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall06/cos528/handouts/sepplanar.pdf) and [A Separator Theorem for Graphs with an Excluded Minor and its Applications](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/spr.pdf)
> - [Graph-connectivity](https://www.informatik.uni-augsburg.de/thi/personen/kammer/Graph_Connectivity.pdf)
> - [Cactus presentation for mincuts](https://www.google.fi/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjkz9mdwdDKAhVomHIKHaAXBOkQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.elte.hu%2Fegres%2Fqp%2Fegresqp-09-03.ps&usg=AFQjCNH2ulMiZHrFzpRrcBetGwAXmo7cpw&bvm=bv.113034660,d.bGQ) in undirected, unweighted graphs